# Obtaining z-transform of multivariate nonlinear difference equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, recurrence-relations, nonlinear-system

I need to obtain the z-transform of difference equations that are as follows:

My problem however is multivariate and looks like this:

$$
\begin{align}
x_{k+1}&=ay_{k}+ x_{k}^2y_{k}\tag{1} \\
y_{k+1}&=b+(1-a)y_{k} - x_{k}^2y_{k}\tag{2}\\
\end{align}
$$

where $a$,$b$ are positive constants.

What would be the z-transform of the above equations? In particular how does one treat the $x_{k}^2y_{k}$ term when taking the z transform? I know the z transform of linear difference equations is simple, for instance
$x_{k+1}=2x_{k}$ is transformed as $zX(z)-zx_{0}=2X(z)$

But how do I take a z-transform of equations (1) and (2)? If you could guide me to any relevant literature that addresses this issue as well I would be grateful.

Regards

Comment: This is *extremely* unlikely to have a closed form solution. At best you can get some form of asymptotic approximation or bounds.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. I am simply trying to obain the z-transform to this equation. I have obtained the solution already using Forward-Euler integration. However, the reason I want the z-transform is that I aim to then convert it into a "holomorphically embeddded" form. Is it feasible to obtain a z-transform of that equation? The only way that occured to me was to use the fundamental z-transform equation of summation for the non-linear term. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this (as I can think of) is to use the basic summation formula of z-transform in terms of the iterates and obtain the z-transform. My intention of asking the question was, is there a way to obtain an expression (like zX^2(z).Y(z)) for the solution instead of the summation?